# Remove "children": [] from json object if children empty typescript

Tags: angular

Remove "children": [] from json object  if children empty typescript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're still writing javascript, so just `delete` the property if it's empty.

```js
const obj = {
  id: 123,
  children: []
};

console.log('obj: ', obj);

if (obj.children.length === 0) {
  delete obj.children;
}

console.log('obj: ', obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

`const filteredObject = obj.filter((item) => item.children.length > 0);`

where obj is your object